# Can anybody tell me who this artist is?

Tags: translation

I was wondering if anyone would know who this artist is.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, it is 陳學[信](http://sf.zdic.net/sf/zs/1225/92b4b5a52a41959326c2b749d789bc82.html).
Chén xué-xìn

二千零三年秋寫園中一景
学信并記

二千零三年： 2003 A.D.
秋： autumn; fall
寫（写）： [to draw; to sketch; to paint](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/5199.htm)
園中一景： a scene in the Summer Palace (頤和園)

学（學）信： （署名） the signature of the author
并（並）： and; also; together with
記： to note; to comment; to remark

寫并記 means "painted and remarked".

Answer (score -1):

I think it's Wu Guanzhong but I might be wrong!

Comment: I would love to really know if this is him or chen xue xin or wu guanzhong because I have a huge collection and some are very large and some are on very light rice paper